# How do I access Twitter if my school has blocked it?

Tags: twitter

My school has blocked Twitter on the school admin, so I can't get onto the site. Is there any way I can access it or unblock it from my device? I need to contact someone before 3pm to ask about something.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to send an SMS to Twitter shortcode

- [Twitter via SMS FAQs](https://support.twitter.com/articles/14014)
- [Tweeting via text message](https://support.twitter.com/articles/14226)
- [Twitter's supported mobile carriers](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170024)

Answer (score 0):

Use proxy server. 
Many apps like psiphon, better net can help you access blocked sites on your network. 
Note: Don't use sites blocked by government agencies

Comment: The problem with this is that if a school has blocked Twitter, they've probably blocked any site with proxy services, too. (I know every school I've been to has.) Otherwise, this would work.